# Theory about Object Relation Mapping methodlogy

Tags: architecture, orm, theory

Are there any books or theory how orm systems should be designed or how they should be architecturaly designed .I want to give these to a fresh developer so that they can understand the internals of what they are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay?
Some practical, some theory :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647984/book-recomendation-on-orm